# Post request to Pardot FormHandler with Axios, CORS issue

Tags: axios, pardot

I am trying to do post request with **Axios** to **Pardot FormHandler**, but couldn't send the data. Pardot throws CORS error. I did some search and it's looks like `pardot` form doesn't take any data that is coming from Axios/Ajax. So to prevent this, I tried to send it as `formdata` which is like below...

```
submit(){
  var bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.append('LastName', "test");
  bodyFormData.append('FirstName', "test");
  bodyFormData.append('email', "example@gmail.com");

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://go.pardot.com/l/pardotformurl',
    data: bodyFormData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
  })
  .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
  })

},
```

I am sending it as `formdata` but still an error. By the way. If I don't use axios and just send it as a `<form actions="/" method="post" />` then it's goes without a problem. But, I need to use `axios` for this job. So is there anyway to achieve this problem..?

Answer (score 0):

Pardot doesn't support submitting data to form handlers via axios, fetch or XHR. When attempting to submit data to a form handler using that, you will likely see errors like:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '{page from which form handler should be getting submitted on client's website}' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is what's known as CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). Pardot doesn't currently support CORS or JSONP for form handlers. It is possible to simulate a JSONP response by setting the Success and Error URLs for the form handler to be JavaScript URLs that execute Success and Error callbacks, respectively.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to do this JSONP simulation ? I need this ? Will I need something to change on the server side ? the backend ? or everything from the frontend ? any help would be much appreciated here ..